# react params - Warning: Unknown prop `params` on <a> tag. Remove this prop from the element

Tags: reactjs, meteor, parameters, react-router

I am trying to make a profile page with react router and `Warning: Unknown prop params on <a> tag. Remove this prop from the element.`  I am trying to pass params to a route so each user has their own unique page loaded with their content.  The solution I got was from 2015 and I don't know if they had removed it.  Is there a new/updated version of passing params into the path of a route or am I doing something wrong?

```
<Route component={userProfile} path="/user/:userId" userIdentity={Meteor.userId()}/>

<p><Link to="/userProfile/:userId" params={{userId: Meteor.userId()}}>My Profile</Link></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just trying to pass the `userId` as a param? You can access it in your Link'd component `<UserProfile />` by calling `this.props.match.params.userId` and going from there.

Comment: This does not work for me.  Does anyone have an explanation or reference?

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this

```
<Link to={`user/${Meteor.userId()}`} />
```

i.e. Construct the static route you want to link to, with the user id. Nothing more complex than that.

Comment: is it possible to have a Route with multiple paths that renders the same component?

Comment: Yes, you already had that in the route in your question `<Route path="user/:userId" />`. I don't see how the accepted answer solves your problem - the warning you describe occurs because you've passed an unnecessary `params` param to `<Link`. Anyway, glad your issue was solved either way!

Comment: Yes yours did help with the warning but it did not help with the entirety of my problem